# Jenkins - Delete Publish HTML Reports after X amount of days , or some variant?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

As a test developer - I would like to retain about a week worth's of test run reports. After a week delete the old reports including screenshots.

Currently using SerenityBDD to grab the screenshots and create the report.

And Jenkins to run the `Post-build Actions` Publish HTML Report action with both `Keep past HTML reports` and `Always link to past build` checked.

Is there a plugin that I can install to delete old reports automatically?

My goal is to conserve space, but also retain about a week's worth of report for test comparisons - specifically the screenshots.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do it by a shell script after the publish stage  in the pipeline groovy script

```
stage('Archive Reports'){
        sh '''
        find ./reports/ -not -name "*.zip" -mtime +1 -exec zip ./reports/results-$(date --date="1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d).zip {} \\;
        find ./reports/ -not -name "*.zip" -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \\;
        '''
}
```

- First I find all files in the reports directory (/[workspace]/reports)

  - except all zip files (-not -name "*.zip")
  - which have a modified time of 1 day ago (-mtime +1)
  - and pack them into a zip file with the date of yesterday (-exec zip ./reports/results-$(date --date="1 day ago" +%Y-%m-%d).zip {} \;)
- Second I delete all old files in the reports folder except the zip files.